# Parent access child private/protected

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

Is it possible, to somehow allow parent to access child protected members?

```
template <class T>
class B {
public :
    void print()
    {
        cout << T::a << T::b << endl;
    }
};

class C : public B<C>
{
protected :
    static int a;
    static int b;
public :
    C() {
        print();
    }
};
```

This will be useful for me to inherit multiple objects without polymorphism(virtual). Any suggestgions??

**Edit:**

I find two solutions as suggested below ::

- make the B as a friend class,
- CRTP

Few more points to consider, while using CRTP make sure you use inline other wise it won't make it any faster(but code bloat may happen). Do not forget to make the B constructor protected(in case of static derived data access).

CRTP can also be used to not transfer static constant data(virtual static const) from base class to derived

The modern compilers use a concept called devirtualization i think it is in most compilers now.

Comment: Make C `friend` of B.

Comment: The [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) goes the other way round!

Comment: I knew this would be said, but the point is why i mentioned only protected data. This is not a valid solution as per design because i cannot add all derived classes as a friend to base class.

Comment: why friends is not an option? Note that you dont need a `friend class C` in `B` for each subclass, but you only need one line `friend class B` in each subclass.

Comment: I find it strange you ask that question, don't you? the point of abstraction and encapsulation is to provide various level of data access. I can see some use cases that is the reason i asked

Comment: as I am the only one who asked a question I think your comment is addressed to me. No I dont find it strange that I ask this question and I dont really understand your comment. Of course there are use cases, look at CRTP, it is widely used. I dont understand why you insist on making the functions protected when you want to access them publicly. However, if you want to do so, making the classes friends is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

> This will be useful for me to inherit multiple objects without polymorphism(virtual).

It's a well known pattern and aka named *static polymorphism*.

The [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) uses `static_cast<T*>(this)` to reference the derived class functions usually:

```
template <class T>
class B {
public :
    void print()
    {
        cout << static_cast<T*>(this)->a << static_cast<T*>(this)->b << endl;
             // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
};
```

---

> I need to somehow allow parent to access child protected data, is it possible?

Of course it is possible. These need to be `public` members of `T`, or you need to make `B<T>` a `friend` class of `T`:

```
class C : public B<C>
{
     friend class B<C>;
  // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
protected :
    static int a;
    static int b;
public :
    C() {
        print();
    }
};
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8a07a93dde03fae)

---

The `friend` declaration still preserves the encapsulation of `class C`, while opening access to a specific interface declared in `class B<T>`.

Comment: I think the answer is we cannot, public data can only be accessed, static directly and non static by this pointer.

Comment: @KartikV `static` or not doesn't matter much. It's the scope, that actually matters.

Comment: Hi, it does matter, this won't be there for static members. Public, unfortunately it should be.

Comment: @KartikV I don't get your point. [Both variants](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f5684b70aa02342) work with `friend`. There's no rule abolishing it. If you need it, use it. `friend` still helps to have everything _encapsulated_ unless you need an exception.